# scalaz-stream queue without hanging

Tags: scala, scalaz-stream

I have a two-part question, so let me give some background first. I know that is possible to do something similar to what I want like this:

```
import scalaz.concurrent._
import scalaz.stream._

val q = async.unboundedQueue[Int]
val p: Process[Task, Int] = q.dequeue

q.enqueueAll(1 to 2).run

val p1: Process1[Int, Int] = process1.take(1)

p.pipe(p1).map(x => println(s"Answer: $x")).run.run
// Answer: 1

p.pipe(p1).map(x => println(s"Answer: $x")).run.run
// Answer: 2

p.pipe(p1).map(x => println(s"Answer: $x")).run.run
// hangs awaiting next input
```

Is there some other `p1` that I could use that would give me the output below without hanging (it would be like `process1.awaitOption`)?

```
Answer: Some(1)
Answer: Some(2)
Answer: None
```

If yes, I think it would be easy to answer the next question. Is there some other `p1` that I could use that would give me the output below without hanging (it would be like `process1.chunkAll`)?

```
Answer: Seq(1, 2)
Answer: Seq()
Answer: Seq()
```

Edit:

To complement the question to make it more understandable. If I have a loop like this:

```
for (i <- 1 to 4) {
  p.pipe(p1).map(x => println(s"Answer: $x")).run.run
}
```

The result could be:

```
Answer: Seq()
// if someone pushes some values into the queue, like: q.enqueueAll(1 to 2).run
Answer: Seq(1, 2)
Answer: Seq()
Answer: Seq()
```

I hope it's clear now what I am trying to do. The problem is that I don't have control of the loop and I must not block it if there's no values in the queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I couldn't make [Pavel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719432/scalaz-stream-queue-without-hanging/29739277#29739277) work the way I wanted, it was the turning point and I could use his advice to use the size signal.

I'm posting my answer here in case anyone need it:

```
import scalaz.concurrent._
import scalaz.stream._

val q = async.unboundedQueue[Int]
val p: Process[Task, Int] = q.size.continuous.take(1).flatMap { n => q.dequeue |> process1.take(n) }

q.enqueueAll(1 to 2).run

p.map(x => println(s"Answer: $x")).run.run
// Answer: 1
// Answer: 2

p.map(x => println(s"Answer: $x")).run.run
// not hanging awaiting next input

p.map(x => println(s"Answer: $x")).run.run
// not hanging awaiting next input

q.enqueueAll(1 to 2).run

p.map(x => println(s"Answer: $x")).run.run
// Answer: 1
// Answer: 2
```

I realize that it's not exactly answering the question since I don't have an explicit `p1`, but it's fine for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if i understand the semantics you trying to have, but generally the process may be interrupted (that means cancelled to wait for some value) by either closing queue externally, or by using wye. interrupt.

When you would like to have process terminate instead of awaiting next enqueued value? If let say you would like to have this on empty queue, there is "size" process and you may use that to interrupt awaiting queue if the size is empty, something like:

```
val empty : Process[Task,Boolean] = q.size.continuous.map(_ <= 0)

val deq : Process[Task,Int] = empty.wye(q.enqueue)(wye.interrupt)
```

Comment: Thank you @pavel-chlupacek, I'm sorry for the not so good question and I'll try to be more specific by editing the original question since I cannot close the queue.

Comment: If you cannot close the queue, you may use size signal as indicated in example. That mean interrupt the dequeue if queue is empty.